# What is a 5 handle when talking about increases/decreases in price?

Tags: stock-markets, terminology, technical-analysis

I keep hearing people say "its a 5 handle" or 3 handle, various numbers like that. I'm not sure if this is related to the cup with handle pattern or something else. And if it is related to the handle on the cup, what makes it a 1, 2 or 3 etc handle?

Edit: The fact it was a percentage of growth was implied, so a 5 handle was a 5.xx% increase in price.

Usage: "You're looking at a possible 5 handle, maybe even a 7 handle"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/handle.asp):

> A handle is the whole number part of a price quote, that is, the portion of the quote to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: That doesn't seem related to technical analysis, but maybe the OP was wrongly assuming it was.

Comment: @D Stanley I definitely could have assumed that incorrectly.

Comment: @Nanoman So would a 5 handle be 5 times the previous handle or just 5.xxx? I don't know if 5.xxx would make sense with the context I keep hearing it used, but that could be due to my bad assumptions.

Comment: or is it something with a 5-digit price?

Comment: @MarcelinoLuceroIII Normally 5.xxx. Maybe you could put more info on the context in the question.

Comment: @nanoman It was talking about gains and losses, sorry I know thats not much, I'll keep an ear out and see if your answer works, if not then I'll come back and add more context. It probably does and it was just my assumptions getting in the way.

Comment: @user253751 I don't think so but that is a good possible interpretation, usually its said like this: "we could be looking at a possible 5 handle, maybe even a 7 handle", when talking about a price going up or down, I don't think they were always a stock worth $5 or that range though. Ohh it may have been a percentage they were talking about! Ok then this does make sense. It did seem like a size of growth they were talking about, the percentage was implied I think. Thank you guys.